# Display React Dynamic text + a Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

i have a react ternary condition in my return. i need show a dynamic text with an imported component. if i use one-by-one; that OK! but when use them together i get error. what is my wrong? how can i do?

```
return (
  ...
  <div className="ini-dialog-content">
   { this.state.dialog_handShaking && 
      (txt.credentialcheck.msg).replace('$$', this.state.clientnet.mac)
      <CircularProgress className={classes.progress} style={{ color: purple[500] }} thickness={1} />
   }
  ...
  </div>
)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not using ternary but logical AND operator (but it applies to both). Operator must be followed by the expression which is in your case only the first line with `replace` statement. You need to wrap it with an element:

```
{ this.state.dialog_handShaking && 
  <div>
    (txt.credentialcheck.msg).replace('$$', this.state.clientnet.mac)
    <CircularProgress className={classes.progress} style={{ color: purple[500] }} thickness={1} />
  </div>
}
```

Or even better with react's [fragment](https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html):

```
{ this.state.dialog_handShaking && 
  <React.Fragment>
    (txt.credentialcheck.msg).replace('$$', this.state.clientnet.mac)
    <CircularProgress className={classes.progress} style={{ color: purple[500] }} thickness={1} />
  </React.Fragment>
}
```

Comment: thanks @madox2. but when i do this, i get an warning for "<div> cannot appear as a descendant of <p>."

Comment: @user3188348 then wrap it with other element (e.g. `span`) or `Fragment`

Comment: i wrapped CircularProgress with <span> too, but i get same warning.